# Pickerview not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

My pickerview is not displaying for some reason even after reloading all components. I click start and it just does not load up the pickerview as I want this to load and then you can select an option and go to the next question?

```
import UIKit

class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!


@IBAction func Next(_ sender: Any) {
    cQuestion.currentQuestion = cQuestion.currentQuestion + 1
    pickerview.reloadAllComponents()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//var LabelText: String = ""
//var arrayOfQuestions: [String] = ["&","&&","||","None of above"]
//var correctAns:String = ""
//var currentQuestion = 0

let cQuestion = Questions()


//init(arrayOfQuestions:String, correctAns:String, LabelText:String) {
    //self.arrayOfQuestions = [arrayOfQuestions]
   // self.correctAns = correctAns
   // self.LabelText = LabelText
//}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    itemLabel.text = cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[0]
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{

    if(cQuestion.currentQuestion == 0) {
        Question.text = "Q1. Which is a logical OR operator"
        return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions.count
    }   else if (cQuestion.currentQuestion == 1) {
        Question.text = "Q2. Compiler generates_file"
        return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions.count
    }
    hide()
    Question.text = "You have finished"
    Next.isHidden = true
    return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions.count

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?{

    if(cQuestion.currentQuestion == 0) {
        return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[row]
    } else if (cQuestion.currentQuestion == 1) {
        return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[row]
    }
    return cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[row]

}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    if (cQuestion.currentQuestion == 0) {
        let itemSelected = cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[row]
        itemLabel.text = itemSelected
    } else if (cQuestion.currentQuestion == 1) {
        let itemSelected = cQuestion.arrayOfQuestions[row]
        itemLabel.text = itemSelected
    }
}

func hide() {
    pickerview.isHidden = true
    itemLabel.isHidden = true
} 
}
```

Comment: How do you create your picker view? Do you have it set up in a storyboard? Did you remember to connect the delegate link to your view controller? If you don't do that, your delegate methods won't be called and the picker will be empty.

Comment: or you could also just use `pickerView.delegate = self, pickerview.dataSource = self`

Answer (score 0):

My guess: it looks like as soon as `numberOfRowsInComponent` is called (which it does as soon as it prepares to be added to the view) you also call `hide()` which in turns seems to set your `pickerView` to `isHidden = true`.  I don't see anywhere in your code where `isHidden` is subsequently set to `false`.

If that happens to not be the case, also check what the value of `pickerview.dataSource` is to make sure it's not nil.